# which is the most stable and tested version of apache solr on hdfs or maprfs

Tags: solr, hdfs, mapr

I am trying to setup solr in my project, want to know which is the most stable and tested version of solr available. I want to use mapr filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are two rules for all Solr releases:

1. They all have a large number of tests to pass before release.
2. Still, there's some issue with every .0 release, so it's wise to choose the bugfixed .1 even later releases.
3. Bonus: This applies to every type of file system you want Solr to run on.

Then there is a trade-off between having the latest features and having it around in field use for longer time. Of course, version 3.6 was thoroughly tested in the field, because it's been around for many years. But it's so outdated you should not choose it. The same applies for the 4.x branch.

On the other end, there's the 6.x branch which has many cool new features but is relatively young. So personally, I recommend you to go with the latest release of the 5.x branch. While the 5.0 release had many new features introduced, the work up to the latest released version 5.5.4 had many fixes applied and still gets backports for things that are fixed in the 6.x branch.